# Paypal payment change after confirmation

Tags: paypal, e-commerce

How can a Paypal payment be changed *after* it has been confirmed on the Paypal site?

When a Paypal payment is to be made, the user is taken from the vendor site to Paypal where he/she logs in. The bill is then presented, the user confirms the payment and is returned to the vendor site.  The value charged by Paypal and by the vendor **can change** between confirmation on the Paypal site and the return to the vedor.  I know this because it just happened to me.  Does anyone know how this can be possible?

**Additional Detail**

The product I bought was for $14.99.  There is a related product that I had bought a month ago that costs $34.99. These products complement one another (subscriptions).  The vedor site showed the product and its $14.99 price.  I clicked to be taken to Paypal where the price was shown as $14.99 and the Euro equivalent was also shown. I **know**  that it showed me the correct price, as I was initially surprised that it was around 12 and not the 14.99 I expected (until a few milliseconds later I realised that it was the converted, Euro price - my Paypal account is Euro based).  When I approved the transaction I was returned to the vendor site where I was thanked for buying the other (complementary) product at its $34.99 price.  I went back to Paypal and found that 34.99 had been charged.

The vendor sorted this out quickly when I informed them, but I have had no reply from Paypal yet.

Comment: What kind of payment method did you use? Specifically, did you pay through a Buy Now button, Shopping Cart, Express Checkout, etc.?

Comment: It was a web form (post) that contained a "continue to Paypal" submit button.

Comment: Unless someone can correct me, but I've implemented several of the PayPal methods and have not once come across the option of changing the charged amount AFTER the user has paid, especially ON PayPal. Are you sure it was PayPal?

Comment: Yes, it was Paypal.  I asked their support how it can happen but as yet got no answer. However, the vendor corrected the transaction quickly when I complained.

Comment: Just to clarify, were you charged more or less than what you were initially quoted?

Comment: Added extra detail to question

Comment: Came across this, but not sure of its applicability here: [reauthorize a transaction only once, up to 115% of the originally authorized amount (not to exceed an increase of $75 USD).](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide/HowAuthCaptureWorks.html)